# How to allow a click in a mouseenter/mouseleave hover div without closing it?

Tags: javascript

I have a "more details" pane that opens up when a user either hovers a mouse over a tooltip, or clicks the tooltip with a touchscreen.  This is simply achieved via

```
tooltip.addEventListener('mouseenter', showPane);
```

I was surprised how easy this was, with mouseenter seeming to work perfectly for mouse hover or touchscreen tap.

At the moment it's closed with

```
tooltip.addEventListener('mouseleave', hidePane);
tooltip.addEventListener('click', hidePane);
```

I.e. any screen tap or mouse click, or mousing away (if user has a mouse) from the tooltip icon will close the pane.

This may be an XY problem.  What I want is to have a prompt for the user to access MORE more details.  So in the "more details" popup pane, I have a line "press [1] to see more" (1 styled like a keyboard key).  Unless they have a touchscreen, and a small enough screen, in which case I assume they have no physical keyboard/mouse and ask them to "Click here to see more" instead.

(I know this isn't perfect, but I can't think of a better way to achieve it.  I could make mouse users have to click the tooltip instead, so the experience was the same for mobile/PC/whatever, styling it with a pointer cursor, but I prefer it to work on hover.)

It all works perfectly, except for the "click here to see more" link, which just closes the tooltip instead.  I don't know how to exclude those clicks from both of the `hidePane` event handlers.  Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If I remember correctly you would check the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing the code.

Comment: Maybe set z-index for your "Click here pane" more than parent z-index and add for this element own listener. Also, how about changing toolTip click event listener when you have a situation with "click here"?